# How can I create this effect on an image ? (Photoshop / Affinity)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, inkscape, photoshop-effects, illustration

I have this problem: I need to editing a ink drawing and have this kind of effect, I think he used halftones and some textures but I don’t really understand the process to make, any suggestion ?

[image]

Link 
http://wylesol.com/#/vinyl-moon/

Answer (score 1):

The Artist describes his process in one of the interviews about him and his work which I happen to have read - here's the relevant quote:

> "I think my process is pretty unique. I do a tight vector drawing, then print it and scan it back in. From there, I tweak colours and textures in Photoshop. I basically do everything the “wrong” way, but it all comes together to create some pretty original-looking work (I hope)."

So in terms of you trying to re-create this feel, you've two fundamental choices: do you literally replicate that process, or do you try simply to approach the aesthetic results within a fully digital workflow of your choice?

For myself, I'd go with Affinity Designer, and in the end, I'd probably make liberal use of the Glitch Kit tools, and probably some of Cristi's Comix Toolbox assets too (really nice dot-screens which are damaged and disturbed enough to not seem mechanical).

[Affinity Glitch Effects Pack at Affinity Store](https://affinity.serif.com/en-us/store/product/glitch-effects-for-affinity/)
[Affinity Christi's Comix Toolkit at Affinity Store](https://affinity.serif.com/en-us/store/product/christis-comix-toolbox/)

But you can do **all** of what you'd need ***without*** buying anyone else's tools or presets - just takes some experimentation - you'll end up with more uniquely-yours if you do it all yourself.

Given that the artist you're hoping to emulate is all about their own unique workflow, I'd propose you develop your own!

Hope that helps!